# Admin overlay forms not working after core update

Tags: forms, updating, modal-dialogs

I just updated my site from 7.0 to 7.18, the forms in admin overlays no longer work, this concerns any pages related to admin: www.mysite/admin/*

The forms always reset back to their previous values. Plus on the modules page when clicking 'save configuration', I am redirected from www.mysite/admin/modules to  www.mysite/admin/modules/list/confirm.

www.mysite/node/ overlay forms work fine.

Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Did you run update.php?

Comment: I did, I have just solved the issue though - I overwrote the existing .htaccess file when I updated. Whoops!